# PS to rename directory of files using only the first 4 characters

Tags: powershell

I have a directory c:\test with files 0001 test.pdf, 0002ssssit.pdf, 0003llllllllllll.pdf

My goal is to use PS to use a a loop to go through the directory and rename the files to:

0001.pdf
0002.pdf
0003.pdf

I keep getting path errors

```
$List = get-childitem "C:\test"
$List |Format-Wide -Column 1 -property name
ForEach($File In $List)
{
    $First4 = $File.name.substring(0,4)

    Rename-Item -newname $First4".pdf"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the original file path to `Rename-Item`, otherwise it won't know what to rename!

Either:

```
$file | Rename-Item -NewName "${First4}.pdf"
```

or

```
Rename-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName -NewName "${First4}.pdf"
```

inside the `foreach` body.

You could also use a single pipeline to accomplish the same (`-NewName` supports pipeline binding):

```
$List | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Substring(0,4) + $_.Extension }
```

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -file "*.pdf" | 
    where Name -match "^[0-9]{4}" | 
        rename-item -NewName {"{0}{1}" -f $_.BaseName.Substring(0, 4), $_.Extension}
```